# Placing GIF file in HTML5 canvas lose animation

Tags: html5-canvas

I am trying to place .gif file(with anmation let say helicopter),I am able to place it in canvas but the rotating blades doesnt work.
Let me know what am I missing.

jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/sajesh1985/ptsdvbrt/

Thanks
Sajesh

Comment: let me know why my points was reduced...Is it not a valid ques?

Comment: Canvas draws a "snapshot" of your .GIF so you won't be able to use the GIF animation  BTW, I didn't downvote your question, but you were probably downvoted for not showing a **brief** section of code you're having problems with.

Comment: Have you considered using animated GIF editors? Try Take-one at  `http://www.take1.de/` I haven't used it for a very long time, but I remember you can edit GIF files with it and make GIF animations with it. Then you can use a simple image tag to make the GIF load and display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle is showing use of a gif, but in either case:

A SVG file with a SMIL animation can be driven directly by the browser when the SVG is part of the DOM.

When you use `drawImage()` with SVG as a source the SVG will need to be rasterized, and when that happens the animations are ignored and the SVG is drawn in its initial position. When drawn the rasterized pixels are blended in with whatever other pixels already exists - there is no separation as canvas is just a bitmap.

The same applies to gif files, only the first frame is taken into consideration.

The solution is to prepare a sprite-sheet which contains the frames you want to animate. Draw a frame from it at the desired interval.

```js
var isvg = document.getElementById("svg").outerHTML;
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var svg = new Blob([isvg], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(svg);
var img = new Image();
img.onload = draw;
img.src = url;

// this will always draw the SVG in initial position
function draw() {
  setInterval(function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
  }, 33);
}
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid #000}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=300 height=100></canvas><br>

<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300px" height="100px">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
  <circle cx="0" cy="50" r="15" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
    <animateMotion path="M 0 0 H 300 Z" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
</svg>
```